# Use Google geo API to find places by name

Tags: api, google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I've used Google APIs to find address based on lat and lng, or with a readable address to find lat and lng, but how can I find places given a name? e.g.: *Imaginary Mall Center*. And get the (nearest if possible) results. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/)

> **Place search**
>
> Return a list of places based on a user’s location or search string.